# Nginx - Dynamic proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I recently jumped from Apache2 to Nginx, and I'm actually loving it.
However I can't figure out how to make a server proxy based on URI or GET parameters.

What I'm actually trying to accomplish is :

> proxy.example.com?url="google.com"

displaying the google.com page.

In another question I found this answer, but can't make it works :

```
proxy_pass $arg_uri;
```

However I didn't find the $arg_uri in the nginx documentation, I tried with this too, but it still doesn't work :

```
proxy_pass $uri;
```

Comment: I hope you are restricting access to this service properly, because this could be anused in many ways.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I could protect it with a http password request, but first I have to make it work. I tried the Richard Smith solution, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter `?url="google.com"` is `url` and not `uri`, then the `nginx` variable will be called `$arg_url` and not `$arg_uri`. The `nginx` variables are [listed here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html). A few of them have dynamic names, such as the `$arg_xxx` family.

The `proxy_pass` directive requires a scheme. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

So you would need to add it to your URL or to your `proxy_pass` statement. For example `?url="https://google.com"` or perhaps `proxy_pass https://$arg_url;` (either one or the other - not both).